# Unity URP custom line shader rendering flickering/artifacts, especially at high angle and distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, urp, shader-graph

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFipK.png)
As you can see lines disappear at the end and it also flickers when moving the camera.

I am rendering these lines using shader graph UV node and `smoothstep`.
there is nothing suspicious going on in the shader graph code so I have not included it.

I am using "Single" precision float.

I tried:

- Turning off every setting in the renderer but didn't work.
- Using bunch of smaller tiles instead of a single large floor.
- Using built-in renderer instead of URP.
- Rewriting shader in vanilla HLSL instead of shader graph.

Comment: This might be helpful to you https://bgolus.medium.com/the-best-darn-grid-shader-yet-727f9278b9d8

Comment: That helped immensely thank you, ultimately I tried doing the same thing, but mine was way more hacky, this one is neat